# Can you help me idenetify this chip on a Sony PCG-252L motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, sony-vaio

[image: Sony PCG-252L motherboard]

What's the green chip below the processor? Could this be a video chipset? Looks like the processor, but the processor has to be at the top of the image below the heatsink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a wild guess and say [it's the south bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_%28computing%29)

EDIT: such a wild guess; I was probably wrong. Good chance it's an IGP:

[image]

Comment: where would i look for an ingetrated video chipset?

Comment: my bad. its right there. It looks JUST like the picture in wikipedia when i looked it up